# Checking a value generated by a method using an rspec spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Let's say I have a model for Dog and it has an attribute for months_old. And I have a method in the model to get the age in years for the Dog like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

  def age_in_years
    self.months_old / 12
  end

  def is_puppy?
    self.age_in_years == 0 ? true : false
  end
end
```

And you wanted to test the method using Rspec and your factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :dog do
    months_old   1
  end
end
```

**How would you test the two methods in the model?** This is my best guess, but it throws an error when I try to run it:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Dog do
  let(:dog) { FactoryGirl.create(:dog) }

  subject { dog }

  context "it's a puppy" do
    before do
      dog.months_old = 7
    end
    dog.age_in_years should equal(0)
    dog.is_puppy? should equal(true)
  end

end
```

The error is something like "undefined local variable or method `dog'".

Comment: Have you configured Rspec to use factory_girl ? also try to reload factory_girl in your shell `FactoryGirl.reload` and re-run the tests

Comment: Yes, I'm using FactoryGirl successfully in other tests.

Answer (score 0):

1 you need not create record in DB. You can read from memory

2 your expectation should (must) be in `it` blocks

for example

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Dog do
  let(:dog) { Dog.new }

  context "it's a puppy" do
    before do
      dog.months_old = 7
    end

    it 'has 0 years' do
      dog.age_in_years should equal(0)
    end
    it 'returns true for `is_puppy`' do
      dog.is_puppy? should equal(true)
    end
  end
end
```

PS the names for blocks `context`, `it` are not good but it is not related to current problem